# MySql - Find record by ID_PRODUCT without notes - last 20 days

Tags: mysql, group-by, intervals

I've got database in MySQL with Output like that.
DATE_ADD | ID_PRODUCT | NOTE

[image]

That is TimeLine status for id_product. It could be more than  100 duplicate record by every Id_product in 1 week. What I need to find :  only this RECORD without New NOTES in last 21 days. (>20 days)
Means: nobody is changing status of produckt for long time.

How to write the query to find only this record without new note in last 21 days.
And show the note order by date_add desc.

Thanks in advance for help me in that issue.

Right now I wrote smg like that:

```
Select  
N.id_product, 
N.date_add, 
S.transaction,
N.note
from Sale S
left join note N on N.id_product=S.id_product
Where
(...) 
and (N.date_add > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 20 DAY)) is null
Group By N.id_product
order by N.date_add desc
```

Comment: In the title: *last 30 days*. In the question: *last 21 days* and also *>20 days*!

Comment: In your example you select id_product, date_add and note from the table Note. What should the query return in the case if there is a product that has two or more different last notes older than 21 days with the same date?

Comment: @ivangreek if some id_product exist (it doesn't metter how many times) before interval (more than 20 days) and not exist any new record (last 20) - I'd like to return this id_product with the last note, and the last date-time. // it could be 50 times in one day (but I'd like to return the last record and note if all exist (more than 20 days since now)) / If some record exist in last 20 days (I wont't like to return this id_product) ) / It's not a case how many times id_product is in a database. Don't need to count it.Thank in advanced. / I hope It will be more understandable what I need it:)